# »Welches/was ist der größte Tisch?« und »Welches/was sind deine besten Freunde?«

Tags: difference, meaning, pronoun, question, interrogative

Ich lese *Duden – Die Grammatik* und auf Seite 308 (2.9.3 Interrogatives *welcher*)¹ habe ich die folgenden Beispiele gelesen:

> Welches ist der größte Tisch?
>
> Welches sind deine besten Freunde?

Sofort habe ich an diese Sätze gedacht:

> Was ist der größte Tisch?
>
> Was sind deine besten Freunde?

Meine Frage lautet: Haben diese zwei letzen Sätze die gleiche Bedeutung wie die ersten zwei? Wenn nein, warum?

---

¹ Seite 308:

[image]

Comment: Sollte es nicht "Welcher ist der größte Tisch" und "Wer sind deine besten Freunde" sein? "Welches" würde intuitiv für mich nur passen, wenn es "das Tisch" wäre, z.B. "Welches (von diesen) ist dein Haus".
Ich schätze "Was ist der größte Tisch" ist umgangssprachlich.

Comment: *Was sind deine besten Freunde* would probably be interpreted as *what is their profession* or something along those lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zur Abgrenzung:

- Welche**r** Tisch ist der größte?
- Was ist der größte Tisch?

Bei der ersten Frage erwarte ich eine konkrete Auswahl und kann als Antwort auf einen davon zeigen.
Die zweite Frage fordert meine Allgemeinbildung oder Kreativität. Die Antwort könnte aus einer Geschichte stammen oder ein Wortspiel sein (galak-Tisch?)

Aber: Der Duden beschreibt hier die Verwendung „Welche**s** ist …“. Diese Form ist mir gänzlich unbekannt. Ich vermute stark, dass sie synonym zu „Wer/Was ist …“ ist, möglicherweise etwas geschwollen oder veraltet.

Wahrscheinlich werden die meisten Deutschen diese Verwendung mit der gängigen („Welche**r** Tisch …“) verwechseln und daher als falsch empfinden.

Entsprechendes gilt für das zweite Beispiel:

- Welche Freunde sind deine besten?
- Wer sind deine besten Freunde?

Das versteht jeder. Aber „Welche**s** sind deine besten Freunde?“ klingt für mich einfach falsch. Da lasse ich den Duden gern links liegen.

Answer (score 1):

Vor dir stehen fünf verschieden große Tische, wobei nicht auf Anhieb erkennbar ist, *welcher* der größte ist. Es ist aber jemand anwesend, der genaue Kenntnis über die Tischgrößen hat. Um von dieser Person zu erfragen, *welcher* Tisch der größte ist, fragst du:

> Welcher ist der größte Tisch?

Anderes Beispiel: Du hast diese Informationen:

- Der 50 cm lange Tisch ist ungehobelt.
- Der 1 m lange Tisch ist furniert.
- Der 2 m lange Tisch ist lackiert.

Wenn du nun, nach der Eigenschaft des Zwei-Meter-Tisches fragst, könntest du fragen:

> Was ist der längste Tisch?

Einen vergleichbaren Unterschied kann man für die Frage nach den Freunden finden.

Comment: Dann sollte mal jemand dem 50 cm langen Tisch Manieren beibringen.